# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator for Merge

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am getting the

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

message for below query. Please help on this.

```
MERGE INTO PS_CT_IQN_ACC_STG STG USING PS_CTS_IQN_BU_RATE RT ON (STG.BUSINESS_UNIT = RT.BUSINESS_UNIT)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET STG.STANDARD_RATE      = RT.STANDARD_RATE,
    STG.STANDARD_HOURS      = RT.HOURS_PER_DAY,
    STG.CURRENCY_CD          = RT.CURRENCY_CD
  WHERE STG.PROCESS_INSTANCE = 22195604
  AND RT.EFFDT               =
    (SELECT MAX(EFFDT)
    FROM PS_CTS_IQN_BU_RATE RT1
    WHERE RT.BUSIN ESS_UNIT = RT1.BUSINESS_UNIT
    AND RT1.EFFDT          <= sysdate
    )
  AND STG.STANDARD_RATE      = 0    
  AND STG.STANDARD_HOURS  = 0
  AND STG.BUSINESS_UNIT IN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT BUSINESS_UNIT FROM PS_CTS_IQN_BU_RATE
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this query seperate first

```
   SELECT MAX(EFFDT)
   FROM PS_CTS_IQN_BU_RATE RT1
     WHERE RT.BUSIN ESS_UNIT = 
     RT1.BUSINESS_UNIT
      AND RT1.EFFDT          <= sysdate
```

Use IN here, I guess max are multiples by the above query

```
     ..... AND RT.EFFDT  = (select max...)
```